# How to ask about out of stock

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I went to Starbucks to get a decaf whole bean pack today and one of the staff said it was out of stock.

So, I wanted to know when it is in stock and asked her like "when do you have that in stock?"

We had a smooth conversation but I'm not sure if the sentence was right.
Could you help to correct it?

Comment: *When does that in stock?* is not a valid English utterance. But you could reasonably have asked *When **will** that **be** in stock?*

Comment: replace 'do' with 'will' and it will be idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic way would be to ask:

> Do you know when it will be *back in stock*?

It sounds a little odd to ask "when will it be in stock?" (though I'm sure you would be understood) because that does not necessarily mean a fixed date. Something is 'in stock' for as long as stock exists. By asking when it will be *back* in stock you are asking for the earliest date that it will be available again.

Comment: I fully understand it  Thank you!